# vh and percentage in CSS?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have the `.navbar` half of the screen but it is not showing correctly. I'm not sure why? I'm guessing there is another container but i'm not sure why?

1. I set the body to 100vh to cover screen
2. I have `.navbar` half of that using percentage

html file:

```css
    body {
      background-color: red !important;
      width: 100vh;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .navbar{
      width: 50%;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .navbarButtons{
      background-color: aqua;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbarButtons">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you should add height:50vh for .navbar class

Comment: Why wouldn't the % work here?

Comment: remove width and height from .all class

Comment: % not accepted for flex height and window height

Comment: @RaviKadyan if i wanted to include an image then, how would i do that to cover all the page?

Comment: flex height? i thought we had use ```display:flex``` for that?

Comment: remove width from .all class or use width: 100vw in that class

Comment: where do you want to include the image?

Comment: @RaviKadyan in the body for example?

Comment: @Umapathi so do i just use that in all the sub elements?

Comment: so you want that your image cover all the page?

Comment: @STOPIMACODER you just 50vh for navbar it show always half screen in all resoulation

Comment: but would that make margin: auto unusable? because when i tried that it will not center @Ranjithv

Comment: @STOPIMACODER becox you used ther flex concept so margin also not working. if you need center align pls add justify-content:center and align-items:center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Side Note: 
There is deifference between: `vh` and `vw`. You should add:

```
width: 100vw //vw is view width
height: 100vh // vh is view height
```

To make  the header height  as half of the screen just add :

```
height: 50vh
```

Working Snippet:

```css
body {
      background-color: red !important;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .navbar{
      width: 100%; 
      height: 50vh;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .navbarButtons{
      background-color: aqua;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbarButtons">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of using `vh` it's better to use `%` approach.

Try the following CSS:

```
html,
  body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
.navbar {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}
.navbarButtons {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: I tried using percentage within the body but it did not cover the whole page just a very small section.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Kareem answer you need to update few of the style, other wide `vh` view height 50 will work across all browser.

```css
.all {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50vh;
}

.navbarButtons button {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static " NavBarHtml.css " %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="all">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbarButtons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```